# Operations on Pandas sparse series don't properly fill

Tags: python, pandas, sparse-matrix

I'm working with sparse data in pandas and have come across something I feel is odd behavior. Take two sparse series (using kind=integer just to make it more readable - the same thing happens with block):

```
import pandas as pd

a = pd.Series([1,0,0]).to_sparse(kind='integer')
b = pd.Series([0,1,0]).to_sparse(kind='integer')
```

Looking at `a`, `Indices: array([0])` indicating the 1 in index 0, and `b`, `Indices: array([1])`. So far so good.

Now I want to perform `&` on these, but even though the whole resulting series is 0, Indices has the values of 0 and 1 (the indices from a and b):

```
(a&b)

0    0
1    0
2    0
dtype: uint8
IntIndex
Indices: array([0, 1])
```

If I instead change to dense and then back to sparse, the series properly has an empty Indices value:

```
(a&b).to_dense().to_sparse(kind='integer')

0    0
1    0
2    0
dtype: uint8
IntIndex
Indices: array([], dtype=int32)
```

Is there some way of accomplishing this without converting to dense then back to sparse? I have it in sparse format in the first place because dense takes up too much memory, and the extra indices/blocks from the `&` are also hurting memory performance a lot.